# Negative $k$ values are not actual states?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

While I am learning basic theories of semiconductor materials, I got this question; whether negative $k$ values are actual states electrons may occupy or not.

In my textbook, a simple parabolic shape $E-k$ band structure is used to explain that there is no net drift current because for each size of $k$, there are $+k$ and $-k$ values indicating opposite velocities therefore no net current by canceling each other. From that my understanding was that positive and negative $k$ values represent independent states for electrons.

But, for deriving the density of states function, only 1/8 of entire three dimensional k space is considered where $k_{x}$, $k_{y}$ and $k_{z}$ are positive values because $k_{x}$ and $-k_{x}$ represents a same state.

However, in that sense, it is totally wrong that saying there will be no net current because $+k$ and $-k$ states are cancelling each other.

What is the missing point of my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two derivations for density of state $g(k)dk$ that often give in text. In one of them, We consider the center of the box to be at $(L/2, L/2, L/2)$ while on the other one the center of the box is the origin. This is simply the translation and doesn't affect the answer for $g(k)dk$.

In the former, when considering $k$-space, One has to take positive values since
$$\psi_{k_1,k_2,k_3}(x,y,z)=\left(\cdots  \right)\sin\left(k_1x\right)\sin(k_2x)\sin(k_3x)$$
The negative values give the same states. But if you consider the later case
$$\psi_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})\propto e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}$$
Putting negative $k$ gives new state. This doubles the states but actually lower the spacing by the same factor (that is $2$) hence doesn't after $g(k)dk$.

In $g(k)dk$, $k$ is strictly positive. What you are considering $\vec{k}$? The $E-\vec{k}$ plot for semi-conductors is altogether a different thing. The negative values are allowed because it talking about $\vec{k}$ or $k_x$ (in one dimensional case).

Comment: In the $k_1,k_2,k_3$ case you're losing solutions. Each of the $k_i$ should be associated with an even/odd selector, so that corresponding term in the wavefunction could be either $\sin$ or $\cos$. Then you can get $\psi_{\vec k}$ by taking linear combinations of the solutions of the former kind.

Comment: There is no cosine solution for the first case. The potential is not symmetric and so you don't expect the solution to get even odd functions. You are not losing any solution in doing so. As I said, There is the increase of spacing between the state in the second case by the same amount as the increment of solutions.

Comment: Why would the potential change, if we are just shifting around in the $\vec k$-space?

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, indeed the version of explanation in my textbook seems like following the second one where in real space 0~a, in momentum space 0~$\pi$/a.

Comment: But I have the following question, if the definition of k-value depends on an arbitrary origin, all k values are relative?

Comment: @soup.soap.duck I think you are confused with $g(k)$ and  $E-k$ diagram. Look, $g(k)$ simply tells you about the density of states. And $E-k$ diagram, for semi-conductor, is altogether a different thing. The negative values are allowed since it talking of $k_x$ or $\vec{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume non-interacting electrons, the current can be written as a sum of the velocities of all the electrons, which corresponds to the traditional definition of the current as the net charge flowing into/out of a volume:
$$
\mathbf{j}=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{\hbar\mathbf{k}}{m}n_\mathbf{k},$$
where $n_\mathbf{k}$ is the probability that the state with momentum $\mathbf{k}$ is occupied with an electron, which is given by the Fermi distribution:
$$
n_\mathbf{k}=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_\mathbf{k}-\mu)}+1}.$$

Provided that $\epsilon_{-\mathbf{k}}=\epsilon_\mathbf{k}$, the sum for the current will contain for every $\mathbf{k}$ an identical term with a negative sign, corresponding to $\mathbf{k}$, hence the net current will be zero.

Applying an electric field changes the distribution of the electrons, making it asymmetric, and thus resulting in a non-zero current.

**TL;DR**  States $\mathbf{k}$ and $-\mathbf{k}$ have the same energy, but opposite momentum, and are not necessarily simultaneously filled.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. However, it does not solve my question.

Comment: @soup.soap.duck I suggest that you think over my answer: I think that your question is based on a confusion about what we count for current and for density of states.

Comment: Can I say that, there is only a $k$ state and strictly speaking, $+k$ and $-k$ are the same state rather the direction of motion of a electron is different?